# No such file or directory loading libssl.so.1.0.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I'm trying to make my first Go lambda on AWS:

My code is simple:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "github.com/droundy/goopt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func badUsage() {
    fmt.Println(goopt.Usage())
    os.Exit(1)
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, s3Event events.S3Event) {
    for _, record := range s3Event.Records {
        s3 := record.S3
        fmt.Printf("[%s - %s] Bucket = %s, Key = %s \n", record.EventSource, record.EventTime, s3.Bucket.Name, s3.Object.Key)
    }
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

note 1: I have some functions using kafka to produce some messages in kafka

I compile it with on my own pc:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -tags static -o goklog producer.go
```

But i always have somme issues like (on cloudwatch):

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 2:
I was thinking static_all was unstable. I tried and I've got:

```
➜  goklog git:(master) ✗ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -tags static_all
# github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka
/usr/lib/librdkafka.a(rddl.o): In function `rd_dl_open0':
/home/maathor/dev/librdkafka/src/rddl.c:80: warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/librdkafka.a(rdaddr.o): In function `rd_getaddrinfo':
/home/maathor/dev/librdkafka/src/rdaddr.c:168: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
# github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka
cannot load imported symbols from ELF file $WORK/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/_obj/_cgo_.o: no symbol section
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RC is AWS Lambda only supports glibc runtime dynamic links, but librdkafka have sasl2, openssl, zlib, zstd dynamic dependency. 
Even you use `go build -tags static -o goklog producer.go` to make sure librdkafka is static linked into binary, the upper 4 dependencies require dynamic link.

Solution:
1. compile librdkafka using `./configure --install-deps --source-deps-only --prefix=/usr && make && make install`

2. compile static librdkafka to generate libssl.a and libzstd.a `./configure --enable-static --install-deps --source-deps-only --prefix=/usr && make`
3. compile zlib and cyrus-sasl to generate libz.a and libsasl2.a

```
// zlib path
CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC" ./configure --libdir=/usr/lib --sharedlibdir=/usr/lib
make
make install
// cyrus-sasl
./configure --enable-static --libdir=/usr/lib
```

4. set LD PATH and PKG PATH using

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=($pwd)/lib/pkgconfig 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=($pwd)/lib
```

5. copy all .a files into lib folder

```
cp librdkafka_folder/mklove/deps/dest/libcrypto/usr/lib64/*.a ($pwd)/lib/
cp librdkafka_folder/mklove/deps/dest/libzstd/usr/lib64/*.a ($pwd)/lib/
cp /usr/lib/pkgconfig/rdkafka* ($pwd)/lib/pkgconfig/
cp /usr/lib/librdkafka* ($pwd)/lib/
cp /usr/lib/libz.a ($pwd)/lib/
cp /usr/lib/libsasl2.a ($pwd)/lib/
```

6. go build

```
go build -tags static -ldflags "-extldflags '-Lz -Lssl -Lsasl2 -Lzstd'" -o test
```

7. ldd check dynamic link

```
ldd test
// sample output
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea7ee0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f772c287000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f772c083000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f772be67000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f772bc5f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f772b892000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f772c589000)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you use the "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka" package. This one requires the [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) C libraries, which in place assume that you have certain libraries - like the libssl library - available on your machine (see the page in the link, under "Requirements").

Comment: Unsure if it will fix it, by the way, but you could try using the `static_all` build tag instead of the `static` one.

Comment: I was thinking static_all was unstable. I added in my question the output

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building your lambda package on one of the lambda-like docker images, such as https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda.

That way your built librdkafka will depend on the same libraries that are available on the lambda target host.